# How to get the ARN of a lambda function in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have worked with CDK for a couple of months now and I am facing a problem that probably has a simple solution. I have searched the internet for quite some time, without finding a solution. I am creating a lambda function:

```
const EventSplitter = new lambda.Function(this, 'EventSplitter', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,  
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'), 
      handler: 'okta_event_splitter.lambda_handler'  
    });
```

and i want go get the ARN of this lambda, I have tried different variants of:

```
EventSplitter.attrArn, EventSplitter.Arn, EventSplitter.LambdaArn
```

but it always complain about Property 'attrArn' does not exist on type 'Function'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#functionarn), the arn of a function is:

> **functionArn** - string - ARN of this function.

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe I missed that piece of information :P

Comment: @smallbirds No problem. Glad I could help. CDK docs can be sometimes difficult to read.

Comment: Not exist in v2 (